# Function from $\mathbb {R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ - real analysis problem

Tags: real-analysis, functions, implicit-function-theorem, inverse-function-theorem

Function $f(x)$ maps $(-a,a)$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f \in C^1$ (continously differentiable). Is it possible that image of every open interval $(-b,b)$ (for $b<a$ of course) contains neighborhood of $f(0)$?

I've tried to figure out this problem, but I have no idea how to do this. I know that inverse function theorem or implicit function theorem can be helpful, anyway I don't see any way in which I could apply these theorems in this problem.

Comment: Let $r$ be the slope of the tangent at $x=0$. Take $\epsilon>0$ so small that the angle between the slopes $r\pm \epsilon$ is less than $\pi/2$. Then, by definition of differentiable there is $c>0$, such that for all $0\leq b<c$ the curve on $(-b,b)$ is between the lines passing through $f(0)$ with slopes $r\pm\epsilon$. The cone covered by these two lines doesn't cover any disc with center $f(0)$.

Comment: yes it is possible : take $f$ any constant function.

Comment: @Olivier a constant function from $\Bbb R $ to $\Bbb R ^2$ have a nowhere density image (a singleton), so certainly it cannot contain any open set

Comment: @Masacroso Indeed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. One way to show it is [showing that a compact rectifiable curve in $\Bbb R ^2$ cannot contain an open disc](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2699323/it-is-true-that-a-finite-number-of-compact-curves-cannot-cover-an-open-disk).

Now note that if $f|_{[-b,b]}$ is continuously differentiable then necessarily it image is a rectifiable compact curve in $\Bbb R ^2$.